# GDAL in R. my GDAL version is 3.2.1，why gdal_traslate() ,error show: GDAL version 2.1.1?

Tags: gdal, r

GDAL in R.  my GDAL version is 3.2.1，why gdal_traslate() ,[image]error show: GDAL version 2.1.1?

Comment: Please try not to post screenshots, better to cut/paste text, and also to tell us what packages functions are coming from.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`gdal_translate` comes from the `gdalUtils` package which is an interface to your system GDAL command-line utilities.

`getGDALVersionInfo()` comes from the `rgdal` package. This package calls GDAL functions from the GDAL C code binary library and uses whatever version of the GDAL libraries it was linked with.

There's no reason why these have to be the same. If you want the `gdalUtils` functions to use a later version, you have to update your GDAL utilities.

Comment: Thank you！I recognize the difference.